# Can I call the child's parent method from the base class?

Tags: c#, inheritance

How can i do this:

```
class BaseClass{
  void templateMethod(){
     methodImplementation();
     if(this.base.getType() != typeof(BaseClass)) this.base.methodImplementation();
  }
  void abstract methodImplementation();
}
class Derived1 : BaseClass{
  void override methodImplementation(){
     .. do things ..
  }
}
class Derived2 : Derived1{
  void override methodImplementation(){
     .. do more things ..
  }
}
```

This would then result in both implementations (things AND more things) being executed.

```
Derived2 object = new Derived2();
object.templateMethod();
```

Then all children and grand children and so on, would only need to implement their part of methodImplementation and it would get called throughout all levels when called in the final object.

But this.base is not a thing. What I need is to call the implementation of the parent of the instantiated object real class, but the code is in the baseClass so I can use it in a Template method pattern.

Thanks in advance, sorry if I'm not making myself clear. I just need to know if it can be done. This being good practice, optimal, recommended or useful is another thing that I'll consider.

EDIT:

The code above is not exactly right, it should be like this:

```
class BaseClass{
  void templateMethod(){
     methodImplementation();
     if(this.base.getType() != typeof(BaseClass)) this.base.templateMethod();
  }
  void abstract methodImplementation();
}
class Derived1 : BaseClass{
  void override methodImplementation(){
     .. do things ..
  }
}
class Derived2 : Derived1{
  void override methodImplementation(){
     .. do more things ..
  }
}
```

the difference being that in BaseClass.templateMethod() what gets called in the second line is templateMethod(), not methodImplementation(), so it calls itself but from the "perspective" of the parent class. Now I'm thinking more and more this is just not possible and creates more confusion than anything.

Comment: You should stick to the terms `Derived` and `Base`, It's pretty confusing what you are trying to do...

Comment: this.base might not be a thing, but just base.templateMethod() should be?

Comment: If all you want to do is call a method of the base class from derived class. Why do you need to make the method abstract and override it?

Comment: NOO, what I want to do is to make the base.templateMethod() call unneccesary for all children and grandchildren and so on, because it's the base class method that starts calling the lowest level implementation and then it's parent  and so on. Maybe that code it wouldn't work just as I wrote it but I just wanted to know if there's a way to to call the object's parent class method, not from the class itself but from the baseClass. I'm thinking it's getting to convoluted and It's not gonna be that much of an advantage, but at this point I'm just curious.

Comment: @mikepa88 so you wanted to know if theres a way to execute a method without calling it?

Comment: @mikepa88 about your edit: it doesn't make sense to keep the old code in your question if it was not right.

Comment: @user3292642 no, to call a parent method but not from the derived class, but the base class. I realized now that it makes no sense, because after the first call there's no way to know what level you're in because the method is in the base class and the object is of the most derived type. Especially after I made the edit, which was what I needed, but at the same time made it more impossible. Anyway, what I REALLY need, is a sort of Template method pattern where all implementations are always called, but I began asking this in another question and thought that I could accomplish it like that

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to call all `methodImplementation` from top level derived class. You can do it like this:

```
class BaseClass{
  void templateMethod(){
     methodImplementation();
  }
  void abstract methodImplementation();
}
class Derived1 : BaseClass{
  // virtual as you want to derive it again
  virtual void override methodImplementation(){
     //.. do things ..
  }
}
class Derived2 : Derived1{
  void override methodImplementation(){
     //.. do more things ..
     base.methodImplementation();
  }
}
```

Each derived class only has to implement his part of `methodImplementation` and at the end call their base class. Since `methodImplementation` is `abstract` dont call `base` on first level. Also mark all `methodImplementation` as virtual so you can override it again.

Comment: Yeah I knew I could do that, but I wanted to know if i could avoid needing to cale base.methodImplementation() at every derived class. It's not that much of an effort to do it, but if it was done one time in the base, and then force all implementations through a Interface, it would be a clean way to force all children to do their implementation and not even needing them to call the parent.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the base method in your derived classes. Here's an example. You can call the base method in each line of your derived class; depending on when you want to execute the logic.

```
public class Animal
{
    public void WhatAmI()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Animal");
    }
}

public class Fish : Animal
{
    public new void WhatAmI()
    {
        base.WhatAmI();
        Console.WriteLine("Fish");
    }
}

public class HammerheadShark : Fish
{
    public new void WhatAmI()
    {
        base.WhatAmI();
        Console.WriteLine("HammerheadShark");
    }
}
```

When you call the `WhatAmI` method:

```
var animal = new HammerheadShark();
animal.WhatAmI();
```

You'll get this:

> Animal
>
> Fish
>
> HammerheadShark

Comment: Yeah I knew I could do that, but I wanted to know if i could avoid needing to cale base.methodImplementation() at every derived class. It's not that much of an effort to do it, but if it was done one time in the base, and then force all implementations through a Interface, it would be a clean way to force all children to do their implementation and not even needing them to call the parent.

Comment: And how should your code know that you want to execute some logic without calling the method? There is no way without writing some code in your children and/or parent.

Answer (score 0):

OK, even if there is a convoluted way to get to do that, it wouldn't even be of use for what I need, and I guess it's no use for any kind of decent code.

Comment: If you feel like this is the right answer, either accept this as the answer or delete the question altogether if you think it's not very useful to keep this around.

Comment: @PJvG I cant' accept my own anser now, I have to wait two days.